# Implement POD to Custom Class type casting

Tags: c++, overloading

Implementing conversion from custom class to POD or other types are quite simple. It's implemented in the custom class itself as a operator named after the destination type. Like this,

```
operator int{ return anInt; }
```

How about the other way around? Can I overload for example, int to custom class type cast?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can, but you do it differently, by providing a constructor for your class that takes the basic type as a parameter:

```
class X { 
public:
   X(int) {}
};

void f(X const &x) { }

int main(){ 
    f(2); // allowed -- will construct an X, then pass it to `f`.
}
```

Note that this can lead to unexpected conversions in some cases -- it's often considered better to mark such constructors as `explicit` to prevent them from being used except when you explicitly force the conversion.

Comment: So if I implemented it like that? I could simply do: MyCustomClass object; object = 2; and this would call the initializer and then copy constructor?

Comment: @ShaneHsu: No. `MyCustomClass object = 2;` would use the constructor, but as a statement on its own `object = 2;` is an assignment, which would use an overloaded assignment operator.

Comment: I see, how about this? `MyCustomClass object = (MyCustomClass)(2)` what would get called, or just compiler error?

Comment: @ShaneHsu: That should be find and would use the conversion constructor (though parens around `MyCustomClass` *or* `2` is enough -- you don't need both).

Answer (score 1):

Use a single argument constructor

```
MyClass(int n) :anInt(n) {}
```